# Multidimensional array: Counting counter values from the bottom to the top of the array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a rather difficult question for me. I myself sat over it for about 1 week and I didn't think of anything.

The idea is to count the counter value up the array - from the bottom.

Below is an example array:

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => xxx
            [cat_nadrzedny] => 0
            [cat_nazwa] => xxx
            [nazwa_www] => xxx
            [cat_pix_lista] => xxx
            [cat_ukryta] => 0
            [counter] => 2 //before 2, after 8. - 6 goes up and is added to the parent's (or child's - depending on how many levels) counter. We have 6 + 2 = 8.
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cat_id] => xxx
                            [cat_nadrzedny] => xxx
                            [cat_nazwa] => Manipulatory
                            [nazwa_www] => 
                            [cat_pix_lista] => xxx
                            [cat_ukryta] => 0
                            [counter] => 2 /* before 2 after 6 - here the value 4 passes
                                            and after adding the value of the this counter (2) it turns into 6.
                                            */
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [cat_id] => xxx
                                        [cat_nadrzedny] => xxx
                                        [cat_nazwa] => xxx
                                        [nazwa_www] => 
                                        [cat_pix_lista] => xxx
                                        [cat_ukryta] => 0
                                        [counter] => 2 /* value before 2 after 4 
                                                       (sum of values the counters the childrens, and value of counter the parent )
                                                        from the bottom - last child value = 1 and first child value = 1
                                                       and parent value = 2. This gives us 1 + 1 + 2 = 4 as the counter of the parent
                                                       (but the parent is also a child of the array up one level).
                                                       */
                                        [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                [cat_id] => xxx
                                                                [cat_nadrzedny] => xxx
                                                                [cat_nazwa] => xxx
                                                                [nazwa_www] => 
                                                                [cat_pix_lista] => xxx
                                                                [cat_ukryta] => 0
                                                                [counter] => 1 //value before 1 after 1 - first child
                                                                [children] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                        
                                                                                )
                                                        [1] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                [cat_id] => xxx
                                                                [cat_nadrzedny] => xxx
                                                                [cat_nazwa] => xxx
                                                                [nazwa_www] => 
                                                                [cat_pix_lista] => xxx
                                                                [cat_ukryta] => 0
                                                                [counter] => 1 // value before1, after 1 - last child.
                                                                [children] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                        
                                                                                )
                                                                    )
                                                        )
                                            )
                                )
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

**Important !!!**

Counters (counter values) should be counted from the bottom up, not from the top down - I tried to do a recursive function but it didn't work out a bit.

**UPDATE!!!:**

Looking from below:
The first child is 1, the second child is 1, the parent is 2 == so we add the children's counter value and the parent's value - hence the result is 4. we go up we have one parent with one child - the counter value of this parent is 2 so we add it back to the previous value, which is 4 (so we have 6).
We go up again and see if the parent has children (in this case we have one child again) with the value 6 and the parent has the value 2 - so we add the child's counter value (i.e. 6) to the parent's value (i.e. 2) again, which gives us the value 8;

**and more:**

The point is that after the previous programmer I took over the page and there are already some structures that I do not want to change, I want to follow what I have and I have a tree structure that presents product categories and their subcategories (it goes down to 5 branches)

There are categories that have subcategories and others have subcategories. the point is that I have already written a script that counts how many products are in a given category and subcategory but as the second iteration of the loop I want the tree to expand and show how many products there are in the main category + products in the subcategory, that is:

```
[main category val 10] // before 10 after 22
[subcategory1 val 2] // before 2, after 12
[subcategory1 of subcategory 1 val 4]
[subcategory2 of subcategory 1 val 6]
[subcategory2]
[subcategory3]
```

*It is important to me, so when it comes to details - ask then - please do not report my account for blocking or restriction - I personally think that there are no stupid questions and each of them can be answered in one way or another.
Previously, when I asked this question - my account was blocked - I just don't understand why.*

Comment: _I tried to do a recursive function but it didn't work out a bit._ Please provide the code you've written.

Comment: And also explain the `before/after` a bit better. `[counter] => 2 // value before 2 after 4 (sum of values the counters the childrens)` Where is the *4* coming from?

Comment: please explain your situation, what do yo mean by counter? does it count the recursion  ? or what? what you mean by " value before 2 after 4 "? and what do you mean by bottom to top??

Comment: in addition, your code is just an structure and counter dosent change anything

Comment: I added more information - maybe this will clarify something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Miguel's help, I made three more lines and it works as it should:

```
function mergeCounters(&$parent) {
    if (!isset($parent['children']) || !$parent['children']) { // no children: the base case
        return $parent['counter'];
    }

    foreach ($parent[ 'children' ] as &$child) {
        $parent['counter'] += mergeCounters($child);
    }

    return $parent['counter'];
}

//echo mergeCounters($parent[0]) . "\n";
// with print_r you can see the modified array
//print_r($parent);

foreach($parent as $par => $key ){
    //print $par."->".$key."\n<br/>";
mergeCounters($parent[$par]);
}

print_r($parent);
```

Comment: If you really want to learn and thus start working as a web developer, you must learn to work as a team. Copying the code of others and making modifications just to differentiate it and take credit is unethical. Read [this](https://1x.engineer/) to learn more. About your answer, if you look closely it does not work, you added a first level foreach inside the function that ignores all the other parents, this is why you feel that you have exceeded the foreach. Instead of modifying the function, you could add this "foreach ($parent as &$value) {mergeCounters($value);}" note the & before $value

Comment: At first, when I tested your code, it counted correctly for me, but only one branch of the main table
So I added foreach to go through the main branches, I don't know if you noticed, but I wanted to add a mail to you to correct me and help me because I see you know a little more than I do. I didn't want you to feel offended by anything, because you helped me a lot. @JorgeMiguelSanchez

Answer (score 1):

You wish a recursive behavior. To achieve this you need

1. Determine the base case that stop the recursion
2. Determine the process to apply and encapsulate it in a function
3. call the function from it self

The key is that the recursive function concentrates only in a part of the job, a minimal part, process this part and pass the rest to it self to run again.

Check a functional example

```
<?php

$parent = array (
    0 => array (
        'cat_id' => 'xxx',
        'cat_nadrzedny' => 0,
        'cat_nazwa' => 'xxx',
        'nazwa_www' => 'xxx',
        'cat_pix_lista' => 'xxx',
        'cat_ukryta' => 0,
        'counter' => 2, //before 2, after 8
        'children' => array (
            0 => array (
                'cat_id' => 'xxx',
                'cat_nadrzedny' => 'xxx',
                'cat_nazwa' => 'Manipulatory',
                'nazwa_www' => '',
                'cat_pix_lista' => 'xxx',
                'cat_ukryta' => 0,
                'counter' => 2, //before 2 after 6
                'children' => array (
                    0 => array (
                        'cat_id' => 'xxx',
                        'cat_nadrzedny' => 'xxx',
                        'cat_nazwa' => 'xxx',
                        'nazwa_www' => '',
                        'cat_pix_lista' => 'xxx',
                        'cat_ukryta' => 0,
                        'counter' => 2, // value before 2 after 4 (sum of values the counters the childrens)
                        'children' => array (
                            0 => array (
                                'cat_id' => 'xxx',
                                'cat_nadrzedny' => 'xxx',
                                'cat_nazwa' => 'xxx',
                                'nazwa_www' => '',
                                'cat_pix_lista' => 'xxx',
                                'cat_ukryta' => 0,
                                'counter' => 1, //value before 1 after 1
                                'children' => array (),
                            ),
                            1 => array (
                                'cat_id' => 'xxx',
                                'cat_nadrzedny' => 'xxx',
                                'cat_nazwa' => 'xxx',
                                'nazwa_www' => '',
                                'cat_pix_lista' => 'xxx',
                                'cat_ukryta' => 0,
                                'counter' => 1, // value before1, after 1
                                'children' => array (),
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

function mergeCounters(&$parent) {
    if (!isset($parent['children']) || !$parent['children']) { // no children: the base case
        return $parent['counter'];
    }

    foreach ($parent[ 'children' ] as &$child) {
        $parent['counter'] += mergeCounters($child);
    }

    return $parent['counter'];
}

echo mergeCounters($parent[0]) . "\n";

// with print_r you can see the modified array
print_r($parent);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - okay, counts, but how to make it rebuild the table and replace counters.

Comment: passing array by reference and using reference in foreach too, check the update

Comment: Cool !!! thanks - you rocked my friend, I did not know that this problem can be solved in such a simple way - but you know, we learn all the time. I was sitting on this week and it took you 5 minutes and it's such a simple code.

Comment: you're welcome. check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/) for more about recursion

Comment: it counts the first element of the array nicely - what if there were more parents?
Why doesn't this feature work if I do this:
```mergeCounters ($parent);
```
If I do as above, it doesn't count - how to modify it would count. @Jorge Miguel Sanchez